# How to specific time for Logs creation http_access in WSO2?

Tags: linux, tomcat, logging, wso2, wso2-identity-server

From this docs https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/5.9.0/setup/http-access-logging/ said about log creation will rotate on daily basis. So, the new log should be created around midnight everyday.

However, I've noticed that my WSO2 http_access logs in directory /wso2am/repository/logs
have been creating by random time.

```
-rw-r--r--  1 wso2 wso2         314 Oct 11 21:50 http_access_2020-10-11.log
-rw-r--r--  1 wso2 wso2       48416 Oct 12 16:58 http_access_2020-10-12.log
-rw-r--r--  1 wso2 wso2       30075 Oct 13 15:51 http_access_2020-10-13.log
-rw-r--r--  1 wso2 wso2       47476 Oct 14 12:53 http_access_2020-10-14.log
-rw-r--r--  1 wso2 wso2       34975 Oct 15 17:54 http_access_2020-10-15.log
-rw-r--r--  1 wso2 wso2         154 Oct 16 02:45 http_access_2020-10-16.log
```

besided, I've set parameters `buffered=false`, and `backgroundProcessorDelay="1"` as mentioned here [Tomcat HTTP Access log has a delay in writing to the file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31109090/tomcat-http-access-log-has-a-delay-in-writing-to-the-file) still no luck!

my Valves class setting in catalina-server.xml

```
        <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="${carbon.home}/repository/logs" buffered="false"
               prefix="http_access_" suffix=".log" pattern="%h %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b %T"/>
```

Comment: Despite the timestamp in the file name, I don't think you have yesterday's records in today's log, do you? May be the server didn't received any request until `21:50` on `11th Oct`. The file will be created by the log valve, only when it received a log request for that day.

Answer (score 0):

The time you see with the "ls" command is the last updated time of the file. So you have not received any requests to the server after the shown time each day. It should not have any impact on the file created time and you should not have any data inconsistencies in the log file.